# Open n different URLs in n different browser windows

Tags: browser, command-line-interface, conkeror

Suppose there are 3 windows of dwb browser open. Using a script I want to open URL1 in first window, then URL2 in second and so on...

Anything suggesting use of Luakit/Firefox/Chromium/Midori is also welcome.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

So after a little tinkering around, I found this solution:

First I installend `xulrunner`. Then got conkeror .tar.gz from its git, extracted it and copied the folder twice; effectively creating 3 folders. Now in each folder, I edited each one's application.ini with

```
Name=conkeror1
Name=conkeror2
Name=conkeror3
```

Then I created .conkerorrc in home folder and added one single line:

```
url_remoting_fn = load_url_in_current_buffer;
```

You can also set it to `url_remoting_fn = load_url_in_new_buffer;` if you want newly issued urls to open in new buffers (tabs).

Then simply issued commands like this:

```
xulrunner conkeror1/application.ini "URL1"
xulrunner conkeror2/application.ini "URL2"
xulrunner conkeror3/application.ini "URL2"
```

Voila! Each window is targeted separately!